# How to handle output which can be string or list in Ansible

Tags: string, list, ansible

Hello i got the following issue. Basically i run the query on AD using the PS command to get the list of OUs. Then i want to compare my variable with that list. 
this is PS command :

```
- name: PS - Pull SITE Sub OUs from AD for specific application 
  win_command: powershell - 
  args:
    stdin: "Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -LDAPFilter '(name=*)' -SearchScope 1  -SearchBase 'OU=SITES,DC=xxx,DC=int' -Server domain.int | select-object name | ConvertTo-Json"
  become: yes
  register: ou_site_out
```

**output when only single OU exists:**
    changed: [host] => {"changed": true, "cmd": "powershell -", "delta": "0:00:00.913282", "end": "2020-02-13 04:04:26.289368", "rc": 0, "start": "2020-02-13 04:04:25.376086", "stderr": "", "stderr_lines": [], "stdout": "{\r\n    \"name\":  \"OU1\"\r\n}\r\n", "stdout_lines": ["{", "    \"name\":  \"OU1\"", "}"]}

**output when multiple OUs exist:**

changed: [host] => {"changed": true, "cmd": "powershell -", "delta": "0:00:00.875002", "end": "2020-02-13 04:25:49.409360", "rc": 0, "start": "2020-02-13 04:25:48.534358", "stderr": "", "stderr_lines": [], "stdout": "[\r\n    {\r\n        \"name\":  \"OU1\"\r\n    },\r\n    {\r\n        \"name\":  \"OU2\"\r\n    },\r\n    {\r\n        \"name\":  \"OU3\"\r\n    }]"

then i set the fact from the stdout as follows:

```
- name: Set list of  OUs as facts
   set_fact:
      ou_site_list: "{{ ou_site_out.stdout | from_json }}"
```

Problem starts here. 
If the ou_site_out contains only single item ( only 1 OU exists ) then ou_site_list will return string

```
TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [host] => {
    "ou_site_list": {
        "name": "OU1"
```

but if there are multiple OUs i get the list :

```
TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [host] => {
    "ou_site_list": [
        {
            "name": "OU1"
        },
        {
            "name": "OU2"
        },
        {
            "name": "OU3"}]
```

How can i then handle the ou_site_list if i dont know whether it will be a list of string ?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based **solely** on the examples you provided, you can know that by looking at the leading character of the output: if it is `[`, then `list`, else it needs to be repackaged into a `list`. The [`type_debug` filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#debugging-filters) is probably the more portable way of approaching that problem:

```
- set_fact:
    ou_site_list: ["a","b"]
  # then you can comment that one and uncomment this one
  # to see how it behaves in each case:
  # ou_site_list: "alpha"
- set_fact:
    ou_site_type: '{{ ou_site_list | type_debug }}'
- debug:
    msg: it's a list
  when: ou_site_type == 'list'
- debug:
    msg: it is not a list, and needs to be wrapped in one
  when: ou_site_type != 'list'
  # it's type is 'AnsibleUnicode' but for your purposes
  # just "not a list" is probably good enough
```

Comment: above works great. one more question - is there any easy way to convert "ou_site_list": {"name": "OU1"} into the list ?

Comment: By [reading the documentation](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.10.x/templates/#builtin-filters), which describes [the `list` filter](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.10.x/templates/#list)?